# Using AWS (S3) via jclouds - how to assume role

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jclouds, aws-sts

When using plain auth credentials I can do:

```
ContextBuilder.newBuilder("aws-s3").credentials(keyId, key).buildView(BlobStoreContext.class);
```

... to access BlobStoreContext for S3.

In native Amazon java api I can use Security Token Service (STS) to assume role and use temporary credentials to access S3 or any other AWS service.

How do I do this in jclouds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

This code snippet allows to assume role and use temp credentials to access S3:

```
STSApi api = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("sts").credentials(keyId,
        key).buildApi(STSApi.class);

AssumeRoleOptions assumeRoleOptions = new AssumeRoleOptions().durationSeconds(3600).externalId(externalId);
final UserAndSessionCredentials credentials = api.assumeRole(roleArn, sessionName, assumeRoleOptions);

Supplier<Credentials> credentialsSupplier = new Supplier<Credentials>() {
    @Override
    public Credentials get() {
        return credentials.getCredentials();
    }
};
BlobStoreContext context = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("aws-s3").credentialsSupplier(credentialsSupplier).buildView(BlobStoreContext.class);
```