# OpenStack JClouds How to build ContextBuilder or something else with an existing token

Tags: java, jclouds

I am wondering if there is a way to authenticate with already existing token instead of getting the token again...

.credentials(username, credential) <-- this is what I am trying to avoid but instead doing something like

.token(token) <- but this method doesn't exist for the ContextBuilder class

Answer (score 2):

Can you use `ContextBuilder.credentialsSupplier` with a custom `Supplier`, similar to the following:

[Using AWS (S3) via jclouds - how to assume role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520216/using-aws-s3-via-jclouds-how-to-assume-role)